# Sections of a finite étale cover of a connected scheme which coincide at a geometric point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi_1, \phi_2 : S \longrightarrow X$ be two sections of a finite étale cover $X \longrightarrow S$ of a connected scheme $S$. Assume that $\phi_1 \circ \overline{s} = \phi_2 \circ \overline{s}$ for some geometric point $\overline{s} : \mathrm{Spec} \  \Omega \longrightarrow S$.
I want to understand why $\phi_1 = \phi_2$.

It is a part of the proof of corollary 5.3.3 in the book "Galois group and fundamental groups" of Szamuely.

Szamuely writes that each such section, being an isomorphism of $S$ onto a connected component of $X$ (see proposition 5.3.1 in Szamuely), is determined the image of a geometric point.
I don't understand this last assertion.
We have $\phi_1 \circ \overline{s} = \phi_2 \circ \overline{s}$.
How can we deduce that the morphisms $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are equals ?

Comment: The point tells you which connected component they map to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the section as a map $S\rightarrow X$ of $S$-schemes (where $S$ is an $S$-scheme with structure map $id: S\rightarrow S$). Clearly this is a map of finite etale $S$-schemes, and hence this section is also finite etale. The fiber of this map clearly has degree 1, so it's finite etale of degree, 1, and hence is an isomorphism onto its image, which much be closed since finite morphisms are closed, and open since etale morphisms are open. Hence the image is open and closed, so since $S$ is connected, its image is a connected component $C\subset X$, which is isomorphic to $S$. If the images of $\phi_1,\phi_2$ both contain some geometric point $\overline{s}$, then their images are the same. On the other hand, there can be only one morphism $C\rightarrow X$ over $S$. Indeed, $\phi_1^{-1}\circ\phi_2$ would be an automorphism of $S$ over $S$, which must be the identity, hence $\phi_1 = \phi_2$.